# How to join two tables in R updating NAs in the first table with the data in the second table?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, left-join

I have two tables with information that is mutually complementary.

```
dataset_a <- data.frame(id = 1:10, country = c(rep("England", 5), rep("Northern Ireland", 5)), population = c(10000, 12000, 20000, 20000, 15000, 2500, 2800, 9000, 10110, 11000), health_rank = c(6500:6504, rep(NA, 5)), health_decile_numeric = c(rep("4", 5), rep(NA, 5)), health_decile_text = c(rep("Top 40%", 5), rep(NA, 5)))

dataset_b <- data.frame(id = 6:10, health_rank = 850:854, health_decile_numeric = c(rep("2", 5)), health_decile_text = c(rep("Top 20%", 5)))

> dataset_a
   id          country population health_rank health_decile_numeric health_decile_text
1   1          England      10000        6500                     4            Top 40%
2   2          England      12000        6501                     4            Top 40%
3   3          England      20000        6502                     4            Top 40%
4   4          England      20000        6503                     4            Top 40%
5   5          England      15000        6504                     4            Top 40%
6   6 Northern Ireland       2500          NA                  <NA>               <NA>
7   7 Northern Ireland       2800          NA                  <NA>               <NA>
8   8 Northern Ireland       9000          NA                  <NA>               <NA>
9   9 Northern Ireland      10110          NA                  <NA>               <NA>
10 10 Northern Ireland      11000          NA                  <NA>               <NA>

> dataset_b
  id health_rank health_decile_numeric health_decile_text
1  6         850                     2            Top 20%
2  7         851                     2            Top 20%
3  8         852                     2            Top 20%
4  9         853                     2            Top 20%
5 10         854                     2            Top 20%
```

`dataset_a` is way larger than `dataset_b`. `dataset_a` is more than 2.5 million rows long, while `dataset_b` is only a few thousand rows (data about Northern Ireland compared to the rest of the UK).

I need to join by a key variable, say `id`, updating the common variables and keeping the exclusive variables untouched. What I did so far is

```
new_dataset <- left_join(dataset_a, dataset_b,
                         by = "id")
```

But now I have duplicated columns `health_rank.x` and `health_rank.y`, `health_decile_numeric.x` and `health_decile_numeric.y` and so on. Deleting rows 5 to 10 in `dataset_a` (delete Northern Ireland records) and add them again with new information is not an option, since the real dataset contains more variables that are not included in `dataset_b` and they need to be kept in place, like `population` but there are many others.

How can I merge both data tables updating rows instead of adding new columns? I'm looking for a result table like the following:

```
> new_dataset
   id          country population health_rank health_decile_numeric health_decile_text
1   1          England      10000        6500                     4            Top 40%
2   2          England      12000        6501                     4            Top 40%
3   3          England      20000        6502                     4            Top 40%
4   4          England      20000        6503                     4            Top 40%
5   5          England      15000        6504                     4            Top 40%
6   6 Northern Ireland       2500         850                     2            Top 20%
7   7 Northern Ireland       2800         851                     2            Top 20%
8   8 Northern Ireland       9000         852                     2            Top 20%
9   9 Northern Ireland      10110         853                     2            Top 20%
10 10 Northern Ireland      11000         854                     2            Top 20%
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you can just index on the Northern Ireland data. You mention ther are additional columns, so I created a variable `wantcols` that can be modified:

```
# columns you want to update
wantcols <- names(dataset_a[,-c(1:3)])

# [1] "health_rank" "health_decile_numeric" "health_decile_text"   

dataset_a[dataset_a$country %in% "Northern Ireland", wantcols] <-
  dataset_b[dataset_b$country %in% "Northern Ireland", wantcols]
```

Output:

```
#    id          country population health_rank health_decile_numeric health_decile_text
# 1   1          England      10000        6500                     4            Top 40%
# 2   2          England      12000        6501                     4            Top 40%
# 3   3          England      20000        6502                     4            Top 40%
# 4   4          England      20000        6503                     4            Top 40%
# 5   5          England      15000        6504                     4            Top 40%
# 6   6 Northern Ireland       2500         850                     2            Top 20%
# 7   7 Northern Ireland       2800         851                     2            Top 20%
# 8   8 Northern Ireland       9000         852                     2            Top 20%
# 9   9 Northern Ireland      10110         853                     2            Top 20%
# 10 10 Northern Ireland      11000         854                     2            Top 20%
```

Note, this works on your sample data but unsure if it will scale to your real data. Let me know if it doesnt and I can update the answer.

Comment: I really like your approach, it's really simple! However, I am getting the following error (as I mentioned in my question, both datasets have a very different number of observations): `! Assigned data 'dataset_b[, wantcols]' must be compatible with row subscript 'dataset_a$country %in% "Northern Ireland"'.
✖ 62541 rows must be assigned.
✖ Element 1 of assigned data has 890 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Caused by error in 'vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()':
! Can't recycle input of size 890 to size 62541.`

Comment: I removed mentions to `country` variable in `dataset_b` since it's data from Irish government, and there are actually no data for England. I realised that and I edited my question to make the datasets reflecting better the real situation.

Comment: Following your idea, I also tried the following: `dataset_a[whlch(dataset_a$id == dataset_b$id), wantcols] <- dataset_b[, wantcols]`. Without any success either, similar error. Look at `dataset_b` in question text to see why I removed the `country` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution in the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org), which should work so long as common variables are ordered identically.

```r
library(dplyr)   # Data manipulation.
library(purrr)   # Iteration.
library(stringr) # String operations.


# ...
# Code to generate 'dataset_a' and 'dataset_b'.
# ...


# Join by ID...
new_dataset <- dataset_a %>% left_join(
    dataset_b,
    by = "id",
    # ...and disambiguate duplicates of column "*" as "*.a" and "*.b".
    suffix = c(".a", ".b")
    
  # Coalesce every pair of duplicates into their "*.a" original.
  ) %>% mutate(
    as_tibble(map2(
      pick(ends_with(".a")),
      pick(ends_with(".b")),
      coalesce
    ))
    
  # Remove the "*.b" duplicates...
  ) %>% select(!ends_with(".b")
    
  # ...and restore the original "*" names.
  ) %>% rename_with(
    ~str_remove(., "\\.a$"),
    ends_with(".a")
  )
```

Given datasets like your `dataset_a` and `dataset_b`...

```r
dataset_a <- structure(list(
    id = 1:10,
    country = c("England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland"), 
    population = c(10000, 12000, 20000, 20000, 15000, 2500, 2800, 9000, 10110, 11000),
    health_rank = c(6500L, 6501L, 6502L, 6503L, 6504L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    health_decile_numeric = c("4", "4", "4", "4", "4", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    health_decile_text = c("Top 40%", "Top 40%", "Top 40%", "Top 40%", "Top 40%", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -10L)
)


dataset_b <- structure(list(
    id = 1:10,
    country = c("England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland", "Northern Ireland"), 
    health_rank = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 850L, 851L, 852L, 853L, 854L),
    health_decile_numeric = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"),
    health_decile_text = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Top 20%", "Top 20%", "Top 20%", "Top 20%", "Top 20%")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -10L)
)
```

...this workflow will yield your desired output for `new_dataset`:

```
   id          country population health_rank health_decile_numeric health_decile_text
1   1          England      10000        6500                     4            Top 40%
2   2          England      12000        6501                     4            Top 40%
3   3          England      20000        6502                     4            Top 40%
4   4          England      20000        6503                     4            Top 40%
5   5          England      15000        6504                     4            Top 40%
6   6 Northern Ireland       2500         850                     2            Top 20%
7   7 Northern Ireland       2800         851                     2            Top 20%
8   8 Northern Ireland       9000         852                     2            Top 20%
9   9 Northern Ireland      10110         853                     2            Top 20%
10 10 Northern Ireland      11000         854                     2            Top 20%
```